# Rendering Knob GUI in perspective

Tags: rendering, camera

im doing an audio plugin. We want to do the GUI in perspective. Here is a sloppy example for getting the point across:

[image]

In this view, the knobs have perspective. This is how we would like it to appear in the plugin. My question is, is it possible to somehow render the knob filmstrips and have them keep the perspective in this view?

When i go to render the knob frames, the camera is centered on the knob, in perspective. Shown below:

[image]

This is obviously not the desired result. I zoomed out further, and increased focal length to get a little more detail:

[image]

Zoomed out, higher focal length again:

[image]

Is it possible to render a closeup of the knob like this and get the result in the first example or does it simply go against physics/science/whatever?

Or would i have to be in the 1st example perspective, and render each knob from that view and solo out every other knob to get the individual filmstrip?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's absolutely possible.
Keep all the cameras in one place and only change the X Shift.

[image]

Comment: Damn, beat me to it! Your gif is nicer though with the split view

Comment: *~ Without my gifs, I am nothing. ~* :)

Comment: ~ *...and my gifs without me are nothing* ~

Comment: Thanks man, i will give this a try and report back if it works!

Comment: This seems like it could be the key. Question is: with the shift parameter, i can basically customize how much perspective i want. What if i wanted to use the orginal camera, straight on, and somehow match the perspective from that view. Is that possible?

Comment: Hey @Rikky :). I don't think that's how the lens shift works. But perhaps I just can't imagine it. Could you add a quick sketch?

Comment: @JachymMichal the very first image in the post. Like somehow match the correct perspective of the knobs from that camera angle. But still be able to get up close for a render.

Comment: @Rikky Oh, I get it now :). Use the original camera settings and position, and to "zoom in", simply lower the camera sensor size - then adjust XY lens shift to 'move around'.

Comment: @JachymMichal thanks for your help man!

Comment: @Rikky No problem, good luck with your project :).